# Animate a tint in android via scene transition animation

Tags: android, animation, material-design

So in my app, I have a scene transition on an image view that transitions it from one activity to another:

```
v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),tracks.class);
                        i.putExtra("album", al);
                        ActivityOptions transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((item_display) v.getContext(), cover, "pic");
                        v.getContext().startActivity(i, transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
                    }
                });
```

Now, the scale and positioning transition works fine.  However, on the imageview in the 2nd activity, I have a tint attribute in the xml to make it darker (style choice).  The tint does not animate, so the whole effect is slightly more jarring that I would like.  Is there any way to get the tint to smoothly transition back and forth like the rest of the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [custom transition](http://developer.android.com/training/transitions/custom-transitions.html). Something like this.

```
public class TintTransition extends Transition {

private static final String PROPNAME_TINT = "com.example:TintTransition:tint";

public TintTransition(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

private void captureValues(TransitionValues values) {

    if (values.view instanceof AppCompatImageView) {
        values.values.put(PROPNAME_TINT, ((AppCompatImageView) values.view).getImageTintList());
    }

}

@Override
public void captureStartValues(TransitionValues transitionValues) {
    captureValues(transitionValues);
}

@Override
public void captureEndValues(TransitionValues transitionValues) {
    captureValues(transitionValues);
}


@Override
public Animator createAnimator(ViewGroup sceneRoot, final TransitionValues startValues, final TransitionValues endValues) {


    if (endValues == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (!(endValues.view instanceof AppCompatImageView)) {
        return null;
    }


    ColorStateList startColorStateList = (ColorStateList) startValues.values.get(PROPNAME_TINT);
    ColorStateList endColorStateList = (ColorStateList) endValues.values.get(PROPNAME_TINT);

    final int endColor = endColorStateList.getDefaultColor();
    final int startColor = startColorStateList == null
            ? Color.TRANSPARENT
            : startColorStateList.getDefaultColor();

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), startColor, endColor);

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            Integer color = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            if (color != null) {
                ((AppCompatImageView) endValues.view).setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(color));

            }
        }
    });


    return animator;

}
```

}

If you need to inflate from XML, this is the way to do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <transition class="com.example.transitions.TintTransition" android:duration="400" android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
</transitionSet>
```

Comment: I cannot get the ImageView. TransitionValues values.view gives mi LinearLayout, which is the whole screen. So I tried values.view.findViewById(R.id.myImageView) so I could find the ImageView and then getImageTintList(). Not only this value was null, but it also was getting values from the ImageView from Activity A not from Activity B. Don't know how to work this out